# MongoDB aggregation lookup, push output of both collections into sub objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

https://mongoplayground.net/p/xQp-y1iXUtZ

There are 2 collections:

1. profile
2. subs

After a lookup, the foreign collection is returned as an array. Since there can be only one element in that array (a sub can only have one profile), we take the first one.

Now, I would like to "push" the "subs" collection into an object as well. There are a lot of fields in "subs".

This is what I have:

```
[
  {
    "PROFILE0": {
      "_id": "1",
      "name": "gk"
    },
    "_id": "1",
    "f1": "f1",
    "f2": "f1",
    "f3": "f1",
    "f4": "f1",
    "username": "gk"
  },
  {
    "PROFILE0": {
      "_id": "1",
      "name": "gk"
    },
    "_id": "2",
    "f1": "f1",
    "f2": "f3",
    "f3": "f4",
    "f4": "f5",
    "username": "gk"
  }
]
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
[
  {
    "PROFILE0": {
      "_id": "1",
      "name": "gk"
    },
    "SUBS": {
      "_id": "1",
      "f1": "f1",
      "f2": "f1",
      "f3": "f1",
      "f4": "f1",
      "username": "gk"
    }
  },
  {
    "PROFILE0": {
      "_id": "1",
      "name": "gk"
    },
    "SUBS": {
      "_id": "2",
      "f1": "f1",
      "f2": "f3",
      "f3": "f4",
      "f4": "f5",
      "username": "gk"
    }

  }
]
```

Essentially the contents of the "local" collection also as an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add projection before lookup,

- `$project` to create a field `SUBS` and set `$$ROOT` as the value that is the root document
- `$lookup` to join profile collection, pass `SUBS.username` as localField, and set `PROFILE0` as `as` value, and we don't need `$unset` stage
- `$set` same as you did

```
db.subs.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      SUBS: "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "profile",
      localField: "SUBS.username",
      foreignField: "name",
      as: "PROFILE0"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "PROFILE0": { $arrayElemAt: ["$PROFILE0", 0] }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SO7CdOcgJ4s)